# str_replace is replacing all the string?

Tags: php

I have this function to convert image url to an image.

eg.

```
$titulo = "text some text http://www.unityofroanokevalley.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/05/2017Apr30smiley-face.jpg text text";

 if(preg_match('/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))/', $titulo, $matches)){
    $titulo = str_replace($titulo, $matches[0], "<img src=\"$matches[0]\">");
 }
```

the problem is it will output only the image on the $titulo, it will not output the texts, only the `<img`... what is wrong.

Comment: the parameters in str_replace are in the wrong order. [read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)!

Comment: @Jeff I read, but can't find what is wrong.

Comment: the order is: needle - replace - haystack. I suppose you wanna search inside `$titulo` for `$matches[0]` and replace with '<img...>', right?

Comment: str_replace($matches[0], "<img src=\"$matches[0]\">", $titulo);

Comment: it's a bingo!          ...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `str_replace()` is straightforward

```
str_replace($searchFor,  $replaceWith,  $originalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$titulo = "text some text http://www.unityofroanokevalley.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/05/2017Apr30smiley-face.jpg text text";
$pattern = '/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))/';
 if(preg_match($pattern, $titulo, $matches)){
    $titulo = str_ireplace( $matches[0], '<img src="'.$matches[0].'" width="60px">',$titulo);
 }
 print($titulo);
?>
```